# Using Contains in a Where clause is causing error: 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'd like to check for the length of the the `int[]` array. If there is not

```
public List<Parent_Company> GetParentCompany(params int[] clientIds)
{
  IEnumerable<Companie> ccs;
  if (clientIds.Length == 0)
     ccs = _xciRepository.GetAll<Companie>();
  else if (clientIds.Length == 1)
     ccs = _xciRepository.Find<Companie>(x => x.CustCompID == clientIds[0]);
  else
    ccs = _xciRepository.Find<Companie>(x => clientIds.Contains(x.CustCompID));

   //-- more codes here
 }
```

I'm getting the following error: "**The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.**"

And I suspect it's the statement in the else that's causing the problem, the expression inside the **Find** method i.e.`x => clientIds.Contains(x.CustCompID)`

Is there a way to fix that? Otherwise, I've used Contains several times in **linq**.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The problem isn't with the `Contains` its with the indexed property `clientIds[0]`.

Comment: I'd ask why are you using `.Find` instead of a more generic `.Where` or `.Single`?  Why isn't GetParentCompany an extension method of `IQueryable<Companie>`?

Comment: @RobertMcKee, `Find`is not a linq in this case. Someone before me defined this method in the repository. I agree with you that it should have called differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to just remove these two lines:

```
else if (clientIds.Length == 1)
     ccs = _xciRepository.Find<Companie>(x => x.CustCompID == clientIds[0]);
```

You can also do this:

```
else if (clientIds.Length == 1)
{
     var clientId=clientIds[0];
     ccs = _xciRepository.Find<Companie>(x => x.CustCompID == clientId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's there is an easy way to solve your issue - just use a temporary variable, so your code will be like:

```
public List<Parent_Company> GetParentCompany(params int[] clientIds)
{
    IEnumerable<Companie> ccs;
    if (clientIds.Length == 0)
        ccs = _xciRepository.GetAll<Companie>();
    else if (clientIds.Length == 1)
    {
        var clientId = clientIds[0];
        ccs = _xciRepository.Find<Companie>(x => x.CustCompID == clientId]);
    }
    else
        ccs = _xciRepository.Find<Companie>(x => clientIds.Contains(x.CustCompID));

    //-- more codes here
}
```